# How to wait for a scheduled job to terminate before continuing?

Tags: node.js, async-await, scheduled-tasks, puppeteer

I am trying to automate an enrollment process using puppeteer. I created `myFunc` which will be called every day few minutes before the opening of the enrollment, so I can have the time to login and go to the specific webpage. Then, a nested `scheduleJob` is used to click a button when it's available.

My problem is that the browser is closed before triggering this job. Is there anyway to wait for the scheduled job before closing the browser? I have tried adding `await` before the job, and putting `browser.close();` inside the `scheduleJob` but in vain.

```
const myFunc = async (arg_1, arg_2, rule_arg) => {
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });
  
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  
  // some code here to login and go to a specific page

  schedule.scheduleJob(rule_arg, function(){
    page.click('button[id="btnID"]');
  });

  browser.close();
};
```

Comment: just move browser.close() into the callback.

Answer (score 0):

How about opening the browser only when you want the scheduled job to run?

```
const myFunc = async (arg_1, arg_2, rule_arg) => {
  schedule.scheduleJob(rule_arg, function(){
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false
    });
    
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    
    // some code here to login and go to a specific page

    page.click('button[id="btnID"]');

    browser.close();
  });
};
```